# running 'describe' command on a Graphical ij tool

Tags: derby

Is there a graphical tool (GUI) to execute *ij* 'describe' commands on Derby DB, outside the *ij* prompt?

I tried to use Netbeans, SQuirreL and DbVisualzer but it doesn't seem to help.

The error is always:

**[Error Code: -1, SQL State: 42X01]  Syntax error: Encountered "describe" at line 1, column 1.**

For all tools.

Is *ij* the only way to execute this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is ij the only way to execute this command?*

Yes, because it is not a SQL command but an `ij` command.

Comment: The GUI tools you mentioned should have commands (or other ways) to display the structure of a table. You might also try other GUI tools listed here: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UsesOfDerby#Products_By_Type

Answer (score 2):

Although you cannot execute describe in SQL, SQuirreL should be able to present just the same information for you (like [this screenshot](http://www.squirrelsql.org/screenshots/objecttree.png)).